# NGB-Datepicker - Disabling dates based on state

Tags: angular

I have a date range picker and I'm trying to set weekends disabled, but only if the app is in a certain state. To simplify this, in my example I have a property `datesDisabled` set to true initially, with a button that toggles the boolean.

I'd like for the dates to be enabled when this is false, but I'm unsure how to do this. I found the disable code on the ng-bootstrap site for disabling dates and this works fine, but being new at Angular I'm unsure how to have this take effect only in a certain state rather than disabling the days completely when the app starts.

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so3wkd

Relevant part of my component:

```
export class NgbdDatepickerRange {

  hoveredDate: NgbDate;

  fromDate: NgbDate;
  toDate: NgbDate;

  datesDisabled: true;

  constructor(calendar: NgbCalendar, config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
    this.fromDate = calendar.getToday();
    this.toDate = calendar.getNext(calendar.getToday(), 'd', 10);
    config.markDisabled = (date: NgbDate) => calendar.getWeekday(date) >= 6;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my solution: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so3wkd-qwhyyl)

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp .... [markDisabled]="markDisabled">
```

You simply define a variable for markDisabled inside your HTML.

The markDisabled will be triggerd by a function disableDays():

```js
disableDays() {
  if(this.datesDisabled) {
    this.datesDisabled = false;
    this.markDisabled = (date: NgbDate) => { return false };
  } else {
    this.datesDisabled = true;
    this.markDisabled = (date: NgbDate) => { return this.calendar.getWeekday(date) >= 6 };
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was so helpful and I picked up some knowledge from it. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a `model.ts` file. Inside define:

```
minDate: date.getDate()
```

Then in your date-time `picker.ts` file write the function like below:

```
writeValue(newModel: string) {
        if (newModel) {
            this.datetime = Object.assign(this.datetime, DateTimeModel.fromLocalString(newModel));
            this.dateString = newModel;
            this.setDateStringModel();
            this.minDate=Object.assign(this.minDate,DateTimeModel.fromLocalString(newModel));
        } else {
            this.datetime = new DateTimeModel();
        }
    }
```

Finally, bind `minDate` in html file as

```
[minDate]="minDate"
```

It works. All the best.